# Where can I find more information on why service-creation failed in Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm relatively new to `Cloud Foundry`. I tried to create a service with the following command:

```
cf cs myservice myplan test1
```

I got an `OK` after executing the above but when I query the status I get:

```
Status: create failed
Message: Create deployment DEPLOYMENT failed at 2017-03-14T11:21:36.000Z with Error "CPI error 'Bosh::Clouds::CloudError' with message 'Creating vm: 'machine_type' or 'cpu' and 'ram' must be provided' in..."
```

Obviously the error message is longer and has been shortened. My question is, where can I find more information on why service-creation failed in Cloud Foundry? Are there any logs I can look at?

Comment: This is going to depend entirely on what service you are using. For example, some services run their service brokers as jobs in a BOSH deployment, whereas others run them as application instances that are pushed to cloud foundry. The service implementation will determine where you go to get the logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more output from CF commands by

```
export CF_TRACE=true
```

and running the commands again.

The output of the status command gives you a hint on the root cause of the error:

> Error "CPI error 'Bosh::Clouds::CloudError' with message 'Creating vm:
>   'machine_type' or 'cpu' and 'ram' must be provided' in..

It is likely to be a bosh cloud config/bosh service deployment manifest related, more on https://bosh.io/docs/google-cpi.html